# Writing into existing excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have a .xlsx file in which multiple worksheets are there (with some content). I want to write some data into specific sheets say sheet1 and sheet5. Right now I am doing it using xlrd, xlwt, and xlutils copy() function. But is there any way to do it by opening the file in append mode and adding the data and save it (Like as we do it for the text/CSV files)?

Here is my code:

```
rb = open_workbook("C:\text.xlsx",formatting_info='True')
wb = copy(rb)
Sheet1 = wb.get_sheet(8)
Sheet2 = wb.get_sheet(7)
Sheet1.write(0,8,'Obtained_Value')
Sheet2.write(0,8,'Obtained_Value')
value1 = [1,2,3,4]  
value2 = [5,6,7,8]
for i in range(len(value1)):
 Sheet1.write(i+1,8,value1[i])
for j in range(len(value2)):
 Sheet2.write(j+1,8,value2[j])
wb.save("C:\text.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using the openpyxl module or using the xlwings module

1. **Using openpyxl**

   ```
   from openpyxl import workbook #pip install openpyxl
   from openpyxl import load_workbook

   wb = load_workbook("C:\text.xlsx")
   sheets = wb.sheetnames
   Sheet1 = wb[sheets[8]]
   Sheet2 = wb[sheets[7]]
   #Then update as you want it
   Sheet1 .cell(row = 2, column = 4).value = 5 #This will change the cell(2,4) to 4
   wb.save("HERE PUT THE NEW EXCEL PATH")
   ```

   the text.xlsx file will be used as a template, all the values from text.xlsx file together with the updated values will be saved in the new file
2. **Using xlwings**

   ```
    import xlwings 
    wb = xlwings.Book("C:\text.xlsx")  
    Sheet1 = wb.sheets[8]
    Sheet2 = wb.sheets[7]
    #Then update as you want it
    Sheet1.range(2, 4).value = 4 #This will change the cell(2,4) to 4
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
   ```

   Here the file will be updated in the text.xlsx file but if you want to have a copy of the file you can use the code below

   ```
   shutil.copy("C:\text.xlsx", "C:\newFile.xlsx") #copies text.xslx file to newFile.xslx
   ```

   and use

   ```
   wb = xlwings.Book("C:\newFile.xlsx") instead of wb = xlwings.Book("C:\text.xlsx")
   ```

   **As a user of both modules I prefer the second one over the first one.**

Comment: You should have said that xlwings only really works for windows and MacOS

Answer (score 1):

For manipulating existing excel files you should use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Other common libraries like the ones you are using dont support manipulating existing excel files. A workaround is to

- save your output file as a different name - text_temp.xlsx
- delete your original file - text.xlsx
- rename your output file - text_temp.xlsx to text.xlsx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got to know that openpyxl supports only .xls files not .xlsx files. And with the workaround you suggested, you mean to say create a new file with the content of existing file and the new content whichever I wanted to add and save it and then rename it to original file?

Comment: Yes. And openpyxl supports xlsx flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into openpyxl library.

Comment: Hi. Does openpyxl support .xls file? I am getting an error message as below: InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, openpyxl does not support .xls files.